# Stripe PaymentIntent: Best practice for ensuring inventory?

Tags: stripe-payments

With the charges API, a token would eventually be handed to the server that would allow you to charge against the customer's credit card, and the last step to complete the payment is handled by my server. This would allow you to do something like:

```
// Prevent anyone else from purchasing widget while we sell this one
lock(database){
 if (widgetsAvailableCount > 0) {
  widgetsAvailableCount--;
  var charge = chargeService.Create(optionsForWidgetCharge);
 }
else {
 throw new Exception("Item is out of stock");
 // Don't create charge against token in this case
 }
}
```

This allows you to prevent a race condition where you sell the last remaining item to two people.

But with the PaymentIntents API, it seems that the final step in charging the credit card no longer happens on my server, but will happen when the client calls:
https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment

And it's not clear how long that will actually take (say, if a 3D Secure prompt is shown).

I'm trying to solve the same problem as above, avoiding the situation of accepting payment when there is no inventory left (where inventory was available at the time the payment process started but not when it was completed). I could mark in the database the item in a "reserved" state, but I'm wondering if I'm thinking about this the right way, and how others have addressed this if so.

Comment: Marking the item as 'reserved' before the payment intent is confirmed is what I would recommend. If the payment then goes through you would listen for the `payment_intent.succeeded` webhook event to transition that item from a 'reserved' to an 'ordered' state. Otherwise, the item would be released after a certain schedule or upon receiving the `payment_intent.payment_failed` event. The only other option would be to confirm the payment server-side as outlined here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously

Comment: Thanks @ttmarek, that's really helpful.

Comment: `the item would be released after a certain schedule`, what's the recommended time for a payment intent? What did you end up going with @BenjiFB?

Comment: I have an item in 'reserved' for an hour. But even after that time, I don't automatically cancel the order. Instead, whenever anyone tries to "reserve" their inventory pre-purchase, I first check if any is available. If so, great. If not, I check if anyone is beyond an hour. If so, the person who has the oldest reserved item will have it revoked so it can be purchased by someone else. I cancel the payment intent first to ensure I don't take that person's money before allowing someone else to make the purchase.